# Convert Decimal.decimalvalues in nested dict/list

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, nested

I have an object that is a nested mix of `dict`, `list`, regular data types, and `decimal.Decimal`. I want to insert this object into MongoDB with PyMongo. PyMongo refuses to insert `Decimal.decimal`, so I would like to convert all my `Decimal.decimal` to `string`.

Previously, you could do this with `son_manipulator`, but that is now [deprecated](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/custom_type.html).

How can I efficiently convert all the `decimal.Decimal` objects in my nested data structure to `string`s?

Comment: I'm admittedly being lazy to check but "Is it deprecated"? The documentation is not marked as such. Things like [`eval`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.eval) which I know are deprecated is clearly marked. So if usage is actually returning a deprecation warning then the documentation should be amended. If not then I wonder why you think this is deprecated.

Comment: Sorry, I linked to the wrong page. It is marked deprecated at http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/custom_type.html. Editing to fix

Comment: Good spot. Considering the usage the deprecation does make sense of course. Probably should be a JIRA for this to add a clear notice to the [original documentation page you referenced](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/son_manipulator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly the same problem with Amazon's DynamoDB and boto3.

```
def replace_decimals(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for i in xrange(len(obj)):
            obj[i] = replace_decimals(obj[i])
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k in obj.iterkeys():
            obj[k] = replace_decimals(obj[k])
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
        return str(obj)
        # In my original code I'm converting to int or float, comment the line above if necessary.
        if obj % 1 == 0:
            return int(obj)
        else:
            return float(obj)
    else:
        return obj
```